Get relative column numbers on LazyVim
I'm pretty new to Vim and have just started learning the motions (I am using LazyVim for that).
Due to relative line numbers I'm already quite fast in vertical movements, where I can specify the relative line number and the direction I want to move in in order to jump to the correct place.
However, horizontal movements still feel kinda slow, since I feel like I have to either press through my code by spamming W, use the f or t motion to press through letters or search for the word I want to jump to, all of which seem inefficient to me.
One of the solutions I came up with was, similarly to using relative line numbers, just using relative column numbers and then being able to jump around horizontally using h and l.
Does a plugin which implements these exist or would I have to create it myself?
Or am I maybe missing a horizontal movement option which would be faster?

Plugin requests are off-topic. I’ve avoided editing the Q to avoid requiring edits to the answer. Generally you can phrase the question « is there a plugin for X » in an on-topic way as « how can I do X » (which might get plugins as answers, but can also get other answers).

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

If you're just learning the motions, then :help motions.txt should be your reference manual.
It contains all the motion commands.
By the way, "jump" motions are a special subset of motions.
Going down several lines at once with 5j is technically not a jump.
See :help jump-motions for these useful commands.
I'll share some common strategies to use motions efficiently.
Use a count
You already discovered that 5j is much faster than jjjjj.
The same applies to vertical movement: use 3w instead of www.
No spam, see?
It's less to type and gets you farther.
Even if you don't end up exactly where you wanted to be, you can quickly home in.
Divide and conquer
All the motions in your question (W, t and f) move to the right.
You can become (almost) 100% faster if you also consider movement to the left.
If your target is far to the left, jump to the end of the line with $ and move backwards with e.g. B, T or F.
Spot on
To target a brief sequence of characters in the middle of the line, using search / is very useful.
Especially when the 'incsearch' option is set (probably on by default in your configuration).
While you type, the matches will be highlighted so you'll know where you end up before you jump.
If you mistype, you can just backspace out of it.
Once your target is highlighted, you can hit Enter and go.
Don't move
A lot of operations can be done without any motion command at all.
To change a word in the middle of the line, you could move there and cw.
Or you could just replace it with :s/word/replacement/ without moving at all.
A more extreme example would be Ctrl-A to increment the first number anywhere in the current line.
Keep it short
One last thing, it might also help to keep lines reasonably short.
Human beings also find lines with 50-ish characters easiest to read.
It may be time to rethink that 120 char line limit.
With several short lines, you can make full use of your vertical motion fu.

I'm not aware of any plugin proposing horizontal relative number (e.g.: in a ruler line).
There are a number of horizontal motions that are worth knowing:

0 move to column 0
n| (e.g. 10| move to column 10)
_ move to the first character of the line
$ move to the last character of the line

But there are number of plugins that extend the t and f motions. Some of the most popular are:

vim-easymotion
leap.nvim
vim-sneak
flash.nvim
hop.nvim

If you edit code and have brackets ((, )). You could be interested to the following motions:

% matching bracket (:help %)
]) closing bracket (:help ]))
[( opening bracket (:help [()


Does easymotion exist for lazyvim as well?

Quick reminder that plugin requests are technically off-topic (see comment on OP)

@Canbach many Vim plugins are compatible with Neovim to some degree

@Canbach, all the mentioned plugin are Neovim plugins that are compatible with LazyVim
